# Laravel move() function won't upload file to my specified directory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

For the past few days I've been cool with Laravel until I just hit this very annoying issue.
What I am trying to do is insert a file name into the database as well as upload the file to a specified directory in my **public** folder. I have searched so many topics on SO to no avail.

Here's my code:

```
public function store(Request $request)  {
        $request->validate([
            'photo' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,gif,jpg|max:100|required',
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'phone' => 'required'
        ]);
        $student = new Student();
        $file = $request->file('photo');
        $ext = $file->extension();

        $final_name = date("YmdHis")."newphoto".".".$ext;
        $destinationPath= public_path('uploads/');
        #dd(public_path('uploads'));
        $file->move($destinationPath, $final_name);




        $student->name = $request->name;
        $student->email = $request->email;
        $student->phone = $request->phone;
        $student->photo = $final_name;

        $student->save();

}
```

The file name gets inserted into the database but the file is not moved into the **public/uploads** directory as expected.
Does anyone know why this is so? **PS: I'm using Laravel 9**.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You're trying to move a folder `$destinationPath`?!

Comment: Did you run the artisan command to create symlink (shortcut) to the storage folder?

Comment: @brombeer . I am trying to move to file to the folder ```$destinationPath```. Should it be the other way round?

Comment: @Dhan nope. enlighten me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this

```
public function store(Request $request)  {
    $request->validate([
        'photo' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,gif,jpg|max:100|required',
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'phone' => 'required'
    ]);
    $student = new Student();
    $file = $request->file('photo');
    $ext = $file->extension();

    $final_name = date("YmdHis")."newphoto".".".$ext;
    //$destinationPath= public_path('uploads/');
    //dd(public_path('uploads'));
    //$file->move($destinationPath, $final_name);
    $file->storeAs('public/uploads', $final_name);

    $student->name = $request->name;
    $student->email = $request->email;
    $student->phone = $request->phone;
    $student->photo = $final_name;

    $student->save();
}
```

Then run the artisan command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

PS. I have changed the answer. don't save uploaded files in public folder because it's publicly accessible. now your file will be saved in `storage\app\public\uploads`

If you have run the artisan command now you can access the uploaded files like this

```
{{ url('storage/uploads/'.$file_name) }}
```

Comment: I got an error: ```Unable to create a directory at C:\xampp\htdocs\project_name\storage\app\C:/xampp/htdocs/project_name/public/uploads.```

Comment: did you run the artisan command from root directory ?

Comment: Yes I did. I have seen the file in ```storage\app\public\uploads```. Thank you so much. But is there no way to actually get it saved at ```\public\uploads```?

Comment: Now if you check the public folder you can see there is a symlink created to link public folder to storage folder. when you access the file htaccess got to the public folder and access storage file from there. don't upload files directly to public folder because it's not best practice. uploads should save in storage for better security.

Comment: The image is not retrieved. I'm trying to show it on a page.

Comment: Can you share the code you written on blade template?
This is how you can retrieve a file from storage folder.
`{{ url('storage/uploads/'.$file_name) }}`

Comment: I have been able to do it. Thanks

Comment: ```{{ url('storage/uploads/'.$student->name) }} ```