# Assets are not linking in my laravel project

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

after running php artisan serve my project is running on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`.
I am inserting files on logo folder my inserting code is

```
$request->file('logo')->store('logo', 'public');
```

this code is inserting files inside `\storage\app\public\logo\`

Now when I try to view this file in image there is no image showing
my image view code is

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/logo/eoFICKlGoU8yDoJrLGYfKFsx6Yq4uGvDs5yC9WQ7.png
```

my filesystem default is `'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DISK', 'public'),`
also in the env it `FILESYSTEM_DISK = public`

I have tried

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan storage:link
php artisan optimize:clear
```

But still failed to show the image in . Please help I have tried many method available on stackoverflow

Comment: I had the same issue, but it was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73631445/laravel-move-function-wont-upload-file-to-my-specified-directory/)

Comment: I found no solution there

Comment: All things are working except image showing

Comment: I need to see your full code. You can contact me via my profile if you don't mind.

Comment: is the file getting uploaded to the ``logo`` folder? I mean does the file upload and exist ?

Comment: file is inserting inside \storage\app\public\logo\ folder but this is not viewing

Comment: view url is http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/logo/eoFICKlGoU8yDoJrLGYfKFsx6Yq4uGvDs5yC9WQ7.png

Answer (score 0):

Simply run, `php artisan storage:link`.

The problem might be that your storage is not linked to your public folder.

Comment: I am adding this but it is not working